# Abbreviation for 'further information can be found'

Tags: abbreviations, latin

I am looking for the formal abbreviation for something like "the further information can be found", e.g.: "*lorem ipsum* (**the further information can be found** in table 2.4)".
My native language uses 'viz' as *the further information can be found* and I've found that it stands for videlicet. But in English, it is used differently than I need.

Comment: I like "(see also ...)" In fact, see also [Is there a "see also" parenthetical citation abbreviation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/491883/is-there-a-see-also-parenthetical-citation-abbreviation) I don't think there is a good, exact abbreviation.

Comment: I agree with @DjinTonic.  I think it's almost always unnecessary to state that *further information* is available at the other end of a reference - what else would there be?  Less information?  A discourse on another topic entirely?  A picture of your cat looking at its cutest?  I also think that the use of Latin phrases (abbreviated or otherwise) is disappearing from English as knowledge of Latin has disappeared.  I for one, despite my solid groundings in both Latin and Greek, am not sorry to see them go; better that than to see them decline into gibbering inanity at the hands of the ...

Comment: Rant in previous comment cut short by character limits in comments.  Probably just as well.

Comment: Further information can be found at or in x. No determiner (the). What is "your" language? Viz. just means namely, from Latin.

Comment: I can't see why ***also*** is necessary. Just **see table 2.4** is fine. Come to that, it would often seem fine to me to just write **(table 2.4)** - as a hypertext link to the relevant table if the document format supported that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  To me there is a difference. When I see a reference in parentheses, I assume it will be the source, details, summary, etc. **of** the information just described or commented on. *See also* might point me to additional information of some kind. It might add to the discussion, provide background, go into more detail, etc.

Comment: @DjinTonic: If I had to read text littered with inline references / links to source material that *didn't* provide any additional information beyond what was presented in the actual text I was reading, I think I'd soon get fed up! If the context was some kind of scholarly work where links to source material were *required* (but added nothing from my perspective), I'd rather not be distracted by them while reading the text - they could go in an appendix for those who wanted to see such things.

Answer (score 2):

In many situations, you could use "cf." ("confer"). This is often used as a prompt to the reader to compare two things, but it is also used more broadly:

> cf. is used in writing to introduce something that should be considered in connection with the subject you are discussing.
> *For the more salient remarks on the matter, cf. Isis Unveiled, Vol. I.* ([Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cf))

> used for referring to something that is connected with the subject you are discussing or reading about ([Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/cf_2))

If this doesn't have the right meaning, then "viz.", "e.g.", etc. might work in certain contexts.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility, though not an exact fit, is **[q.v.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/q.v.)**:

> *quod vide*; which see; used to reference material mentioned in text.
>
> > This is described in more detail in Brown’s book on the subject (q.v.).

Comment: No, it's a far from exact fit. ' ... [the] further information [mentioned] can be found in table 2.4' can't be condensed using qv.